# r: how to partition a list or vector into pairs at an offset of 1

Tags: r, partition

sorry for the elementary question but I need to partition a list of numbers at an offset of 1. 
e.g., 
i have a list like:

```
c(194187, 193668, 192892, 192802 ..)
```

and need a list of lists like:

```
c(c(194187, 193668), c(193668, 192892), c(192892, 192802)...)
```

where the last element of list n is the first of list n+1. there must be a way to do this with 
    split() 
but I can't figure it out
in mathematica, the command i need is Partition[list,2,1]

Comment: What would be the results for the last observation.

Comment: `x <- c(194187, 193668, 192892, 192802); Map(c, x[-length(x)], x[-1])`

Comment: nelson, can you please accept one answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this, using zoo library

```
library(zoo)

x <- 1:10     # Vector of 10 numbers
m <- rollapply(data = x, 2, by=1, c)    # Creates a Matrix of rows = n-1, each row as a List
l <- split(m, row(m))   #splitting the matrix into individual list
```

Output:

```
> l
$`1`
[1] 1 2

$`2`
[1] 2 3

$`3`
[1] 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `base R` to create a `vector` of elements

```
v1 <- rbind(x[-length(x)], x[-1])
c(v1)
#[1] 194187 193668 193668 192892 192892 192802
```

If we need a `list`

```
split(v1, col(v1))
```

#### data

```
x <- c(194187, 193668, 192892, 192802);
```